# Where to import CognitoIdentityServiceProvider from?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Well here is what I have got

```
import { CognitoIdentityServiceProvider } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';


var params = {
  GroupName: 'Berater', 
  UserPoolId: 'eu-central-1_YQtTjK3DB', 
  Username: 'testuser' 
};
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminAddUserToGroup(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb: ', err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
})
```

But I keep getting the error that the `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` is not being exported from `amazon-cognito-identity-js` so my question is where deos one import it from? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` is part of AWS SDK.
You should import AWS first from **'aws-sdk'**:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminForgetDevice(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

You can see the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html

Comment: Thanks the import is now working  but I'm getting an error on my concole it says    'ConfigError: "Missing region in config"'  do you have any idea how I can rectify this? Thanks

Comment: That's because you're missing the region in your config params. You should add your region e.g.: `region: 'us-east-1'`

Comment: well now it tells me  " UnexpectedParameter: "Unexpected key 'region' found in params" ". I don't seem to get it

Comment: Try adding it like this: `AWS.config.update({ region: '******' });`

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. This worked but I in addition to the region I had to add accesskeyId and secretkey credentials alongfside the region. Thanks alot @Jose A. Ayllon